# iScroll ipad issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iscroll4

Using iScroll (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) on this website (http://www.bigideaadv.com/adaptive/people.php).

I have it installed but it is not functioning correctly. JS code below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    var myScroll;
    function loaded() {
        myScroll = new iScroll('ipad_container');
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
</script>
```

Collapsed HTML structure:

```
    <div id="ipad_container">
            <div id="scroller">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bio_section">
    </div>
    <div id="nav_section_people">
    </div>
```

CSS is too big to post here.

When I try and scroll, it snaps back to the top position. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the documentation?

> ONLOAD Sometimes the DOMContentLoaded is a bit hasty and get fired
>   when the contents are not ready. If you slip into some weird behaviors
>   (eg: rubber band effect), try the following:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="iscroll.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  var myScroll; 
  function loaded() {
    setTimeout(function () {        
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');  
   },
 100); } 
 window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false); </script>
```

> In this case iScroll is started only 100ms after the page is
>   completely  loaded (graphics included). This is probably the safest
>   way to call  the iScroll.

source: [cubiq](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

Comment: Tried that. Read the docs and a lot of the comments.

The code you posted above scrolls but the footer doesn't stick to the bottom.

Comment: I checked your page again, and the "rubber band" is no longer happening. Is there still an issue?

Comment: I messed with the code and the rubberband is back which I assume means that iscroll is being initiated. Don't know why it snaps though.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the structure of your DOM and how iScroll wants it may be different.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact thing happen to me. I added the parameter 'snap:true' and it fixed the problem.

So, your line:

```
myScroll = new iScroll('ipad_container');
```

would become:

```
myScroll = new iScroll('ipad_container', {snap:true});
```

Hope that helps.